# CSS link to Bootstrap works in localhost but not on deployment server

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fairly simple Django application which I have added Twitter Bootstrap to.

It works as expected when on the local Django server `http://127.0.0.1:8000/surveythree/` But when I deploy it to my production server http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ the CSS does not work.

I have tried many variations of the following links.

```
<link href = "/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet"> 
<link href = "http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/src/survey/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

My project setup.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<link href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet>"
```

here "`./static`" refers to the folder named "static" in current directory and if you are using "`/static`" which means folder named "static" in root directory.
Both make the difference on server side.

and if its not working then you can add its bootstrap link

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you don't use the "Debug = True" on your deployment server (in settings.py).
So basically, Django doesn't serve static files while in production. You can configure your server to do it, as described in this doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/

If you are using Apache2, you can add this line in your VirtualHost :

```
Alias /static /path/to/your/static/folder
```

and then continue using the Django {% static %} :

```
<link href = "{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel = "stylesheet">
```

Hope it helps

PS : If Debug = True is enabled, you should check the STATIC_URL in your settings.py, and every path you use to access each file.

EDIT : don't forget to restart the server if you go for my solution (if it works)